# How can I make a div appear on top of adjacent divs while it's changing scale?

Tags: css, html

I made buttons that grow when you put the mouse over them, but when you switch between them quickly, the one on the right is always on top until it's back to it's original size. It's a bit hard to explain, so here's what I have so far:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/RN76D/

Hopefully that works, I've never posted here before...anyway, is there a way to always have the div that your mouse is over appear on top? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In your Fiddle try adding following property

```
position:relative;
```

to .albumbutton:hover, as for z-index to work the position attribute has to relative, absolute or fixed except static(which is the default one)

Answer (score 0):

Try `position: relative`, and also specify that only the transform property should be animated.

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/as2003/k2uLC/1/). (I didn't test it in anything other than Chrome).